# Error: Cannot find typescript def for ‘node’ inside events.d.ts file

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic2, typescript-typings

ionic 2.1.13

typings 2.0.0

npm 4.0.2

cordova 6.4.0

## update

I added

`"types": [
      "firebase"
    ]`

to the tsconfig.json file suggested from the [AngularFire site](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md). This "fixed" the current problem, Ionic Serve no longer throws the error below but the page still fails to load. The output from the console reads, 404 for both '/build/main.css' and '/build/main.js'

I'm building an Ionic 2 app with Firebase, the app has ran successful so far but now I'm getting this error,

[screen capture of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV94D.png)

I've looked in this file: 
typescript: node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/events.d.ts, line: 1

and `/// gives the error "cannot find type definition file for 'node'

any ideas of what may be going on?

I've had other issues with this too: Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ watch script 'ionic-app-scripts watch'. #256`

Comment: which packages are you using typings for?

Comment: There are 2 packages listed under node_modules/@types  They are Jasmine (2.5.36) and localforage (0.0.30).

Comment: The package.json has this listed though:  ` "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chalk": "^0.4.30",
    "@types/chokidar": "^1.4.29",
    "@types/clean-css": "^3.4.29",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.33",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^0.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.33",
    "@types/mock-fs": "^3.6.29",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/node-sass": "^0.0.29",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.35",
    "@types/ws": "^0.0.34",
    ...
  } `